# How can I remove line above the accordion of Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement an Accordion component with Material UI.

The problem I'm facing is that a gray line is automatically inserted above the component although I prefer white background. How can I remove it? Here is demo code.[Material UI accordion component demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-gagarin-p8mn2?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make gray line white you have to override the css classes of `Accordion` element.

The grey line comes from `.MuiAccordion-root:before` style. So at first change `Accordion` props adding `classes` props like:

```
...
<Accordion
   elevation={0}
   classes={{
      root: classes.MuiAccordionroot
   }}
>
...
```

And then on your `useStyles` add:

```
MuiAccordionroot: {
    "&.MuiAccordion-root:before": {
      backgroundColor: "white"
    }
  }
```

and grey line becames white. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-frost-cjqqn?file=/demo.js) your code modified.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me! Small improvement suggestion: instead of making the background white (which still consumes 1px space), you can fully remove the line by setting `height: 0`

Comment: You can also use "&.MuiAccordion-root:before": {
    display: 'none'
  }
so you totally get rid of it

Comment: You can also just wrap the Accordion in a div and it will go away.

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore apparently.

Answer (score 28):

With the release of [Material-UI v5.0.0-beta.0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta.0), custom styling has become much easier via use of [the new `sx` prop](https://next.material-ui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#use-the-sx-prop).

The `sx` prop may be used on all Material-UI components as of v5. In our world, this has eliminated the need for hack-ish style overrides and custom classes.

Here's how to remove the "line above the accordion" with the `sx={}` prop.

```
return (
    <Accordion
        disableGutters
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
            '&:before': {
                display: 'none',
            }
        }}>
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMore/>}>
            ...your summary here...
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails sx={{ maxWidth: '480px' }}>
            ...your details here...
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
);
```

Note that I've passed the `sx` prop to `<AccordionDetails/>` as well.

You must pass an object to `sx` so you're always going to have a double set of curly braces...

```
sx={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #dddddd', borderRadius: '4px' }}
```

Comment: I believe the `:before` pseudo-element was removed from Accordion in MUI v5.

Comment: This answer also doesn't work

Comment: Works for me on MUI v5.11.5 - still had this issue on v5

Answer (score 3):

Try adding some css file and access this class `MuiAccordion-root:before` and change it's `height` to 0px. It's the `pseudo-element` that's showing the gray line above the Accordian.

Answer (score 3):

```
// in my TS project i did it like this: 
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    test: {
      '&:before': {
        display: 'none',
      },
);

<Accordion
  classes={{
    root: classes.test,
  }}
   expanded={expanded}
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the Accordion component in a div and it will remove the line. It comes from a :before property that I imagine is helpful when you have more than one in a row to visually divide.

Comment: Simple, doesn't change the layout, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 To remove line between Accordion summary and Accordion details you just need to pass borderBottom='none !important'
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
Summary:{
borderBottom:'none !important'
});

const AccordionComp=()=>{  
 const classes = useStyles();
return(
<Accordion>
<AccordionSummary className={classes.Summary}>
......
 </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>......</AccordionDetails>
 </Accordian>
)}

export default AccordionComp;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in this way:

```
.MuiAccordionSummary-root:before {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using custom theme override globally can be done like this:

```
import {createTheme, Theme} from '@mui/material/styles'

const theme = (isLight: boolean) => {
    let muiTheme:Theme = createTheme({
            MuiAccordion: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        "&.MuiAccordion-root:before": {
                            backgroundColor: "transparent"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        custom: {

        },
    })

    return muiTheme = responsiveFontSizes(muiTheme)
}
```